# How to speed the code to perform a double summation

Tags: r

I have the following double summation:

[image]

that I would like to write as a code in R.

Below I present my solution. First of all, I chose of storing x, y and z as random array or matrix.

```
m<-5 
n<-7
x<-runif(n) 
y<-matrix(runif(n*m), ncol=m) 
z<-runif(m)
```

And I have used a double for loop to perform the double sum.

```
ans <- 0
for (i in 1:n){
  for (j in 1:m){
    ans <- ans + x[i]*y[i,j]*z[j]
  }
}
```

I would like to speed this code, deleting the double for loop. Any suggestions?

Comment: Before you move on to the *programming* aspect, have you even determined if it is *mathematically* possible? As a first step you could move the multiplication by `x[I]` out of the inner loop, but that is as far as you can get without there being some other constraints on the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just the multiplication of the matrices:

```
t(x) %*% y %*% z
```

Do `c(t(x) %*% y %*% z)` to get a number instead of a `1 x 1` matrix.